# Rails Postgres ActiveRecord match by intersection of ids and custom array in query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have model Post that `has_and_belongs_to_many :categories`.

I need something like that:

```
Post.where('here category_ids intersects with custom array [1,2,3]').all
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join categories and query on categories

```
Post.joins(:categories).where(categories: { id: [1,2,3] })
```